# Oracle trigger return after update

Tags: oracle, join, plsql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger named invoices_after_update_payment for the Invoices table
that displays the vendor name, invoice number, and payment total in the output
window whenever the payment total is increased.

This is my first time working with triggers and all I am getting is errors
[image]

```
create or replace trigger invoices_after_update_payment
after update
on invoices
for each row
when (new.payment_total > old.payment_total)
declare
vendor_name_var    vendors%rowtype%;
Begin
Select v.vendor_name, i.invoice_number, i.payment_total
into vendor_name_var, :new.invoice_number, :new.payment_total
from Vendors v
inner join Invoices i
on v.vendor_id = i.vendor_id
where i.vendor_id = :new.vendor_id
dbms_output.put_line(vendor_name_var || :new.invoice_number || :new.payment_total);
end;
/
```

Comment: This is a trivial syntax question.  You could quite easily resolve this yourself by consulting the Oracle documentation.  Find the relevant section here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#CIHEIHAC

Comment: I don't think it is as simple as a syntax error, although that was part of it

Comment: ORA-00933 indicates a syntax error.  Although once you do get the trigger to compile you will run into the "mutating tables" error.

Comment: So I should look at the compound triggers then?

Answer (score 0):

Put semi colon to terminate this line like 
`where i.vendor_id = :new.vendor_id;` 
and compile to see whether you are getting any errors.